# JQuery Show Error if No Data Found

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have a JQuery syntax to get data from XML file and place it in a table.  Everything is working fine, but when I try to delete all data from the XML, the error message doesn't show up.  I wonder why!?

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
        {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type    : "GET",
                    url     : "xml/london.xml", 
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success : xmlParser 
                }
            ); // end ajax

            $('#container').html("<tr><td>NAME</td><td>LATITUDE</td><td>LONGITUDE</td><td>GEOMETRY ID</td><td>CONTRY CODE</td><td>CONTRY NAME</td><td>FCL</td><td>F-CODE</td></tr>");
        }); // end ready

function xmlParser(xml){
    $(xml).find("geoname").each(

        function()
            {   
                var tName = $(this).find("name").text();
                var tLat = $(this).find("lat").text();
                var tLng = $(this).find("lng").text();
                var tgeonameID = $(this).find("geonameId").text();
                var tCountryCode = $(this).find("countryCode").text();
                var tCountryName = $(this).find("countryName").text(); 
                var tfct = $(this).find("fcl").text();
                var tfCode = $(this).find("fcode").text();

                $('#container').append("<tr><td class='PL10 txtBold'>" + tName + "</td><td class='PL10'>" + tLat + "</td><td class='PL10'>" + tLng + "</td><td class='txtCenter'>" + tgeonameID + "</td><td class='txtCenter'>"+ tCountryCode + "</td><td class='PL10'>" + tCountryName + "</td><td class='PL10'>" + tfct + "</td><td class='PL10'>" + tfCode + "</td></td></tr>");
            }
        );  // end each
}
```

Comment: do you mean error message or alert?

Comment: Depending on your server-side code, it may not be the case that `xml.length == 0`.

Comment: What does `console.log(xml.length)` right before the condition statement log?

Comment: Your success field isn't a function definition.

Comment: I meant if no data, it shows a message " No Data found".  How to fix this code? @ Curtis, please give me a hand.  Thanks

Comment: @ aharen, I try console.log(xml.length), but it doesn't work, either.  Any thought?

Comment: @abcidd if you get a message 'No data found!' when there is no message then code is running as it should, What would you like it to do if there is no data?

Comment: @aharen, Thank you very much for your concern!  If there is no data, I need to show NO DATA FOUND.  Please direct me a way.  Thanks.

Comment: @abcidd please check my answer if its what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are calling `alert('No data found!');` when the length on the returned data is 0, which will just show you a message.

If you would like the view to update instead, you will need to add the data to your html. From your code sample it looks like the div `#container` is used to display the data, so making the following change to your code

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type    : "GET",
                url     : "xml/london.xml", 
                dataType: "xml",
                success : function(xml){
                    if (xml === null || xml.length == 0){
                        $('#container').html('NO DATA FOUND');

                    }
                    else {
                        $('#container').html("<tr><td>NAME</td><td>LATITUDE</td><td>LONGITUDE</td><td>GEOMETRY ID</td><td>CONTRY CODE</td><td>CONTRY NAME</td><td>FCL</td><td>F-CODE</td></tr>");
                        xmlParser(xml);
                    }
                }
            }
        ); // end ajax


}); // end ready

function xmlParser(xml){
    $(xml).find("geoname").each(

        function()
            {   
                var tName = $(this).find("name").text();
                var tLat = $(this).find("lat").text();
                var tLng = $(this).find("lng").text();
                var tgeonameID = $(this).find("geonameId").text();
                var tCountryCode = $(this).find("countryCode").text();
                var tCountryName = $(this).find("countryName").text(); 
                var tfct = $(this).find("fcl").text();
                var tfCode = $(this).find("fcode").text();

                $('#container').append("<tr><td class='PL10 txtBold'>" + tName + "</td><td class='PL10'>" + tLat + "</td><td class='PL10'>" + tLng + "</td><td class='txtCenter'>" + tgeonameID + "</td><td class='txtCenter'>"+ tCountryCode + "</td><td class='PL10'>" + tCountryName + "</td><td class='PL10'>" + tfct + "</td><td class='PL10'>" + tfCode + "</td></td></tr>");
            }
        );  // end each
}
```

Replacing `alert('No data found!');` with `$('#container').html('NO DATA FOUND');` should update your container instead of alerting you with the message.

Moving the code bit `$('#container').html("<tr><td>NAME</td><td>LATITUDE</td><td>LONGITUDE</td><td>GEOMETRY ID</td><td>CONTRY CODE</td><td>CONTRY NAME</td><td>FCL</td><td>F-CODE</td></tr>");` to the else will eliminate the container being updated with table when there is no data.

Hope this helps, cheers :)

Comment: @ Aharen, Thank you very much for your help!  I try as you directed me, but it doesn't show!  I am thinking (but not sure) a problem is ` success : xmlParser(xml)`.  When I remove (xml) from ` success : xmlParser(xml)` and I don't delete all the data, the data shows on the table.  Any thought?

Comment: @abcidd could you please share the functions `xmlParser()` and `response()` used in your code, i think the issue is with one of those. updated the answer to work without those functions

Comment: I just updated my question on the top.  On this version, I don't have any code to detect if there is no data.  Please take a look and direct me where I have to add code to detect if there is no data.  Thanks alot!

Comment: add the check to `success: function(xml)` if you find data you can call `xmlParser()` function and if not you can display the no data message. I have updated the answer, please check now